# How long do trees take to grow in Farming Simulator 2015?

Tags: farming-simulator-2015

I've planted a few saplings in Farming Simulator 2015. How many "game days" does it take for them to become fully grown?

Answer (score 2):

It takes two game days for the saplings to become fully grown trees.

Answer (score 0):

I highly doubt the answer by @SuperAdmin. According to [this discussion on steam community](https://steamcommunity.com/app/313160/discussions/0/613940477895111691/) it takes ten days to grow a sampling into a fully grown tree.